# Jersey REST service as Spring Component

Tags: java, rest, service, jersey

I hava a rest service inside my app and i would like it to use spring beans.
Spring i am using is version 2.5.
Part of web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.app.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In pom.xml i have dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

In context.xml i have added:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.rest"/>
```

and also:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Interesting part of service class:

```
@Component
@Path("/notification")
@Scope("singleton")
public class PushNotification {

    @Autowired
    //@Resource(name = "sendMessageServiceFacade")
    private SendMessageServiceFacade sendMessageServiceFacade;

    @Autowired
    //@Resource(name = "responseCode")
    private NotificationResponseMessage responseCode;

    @Autowired
    //@Resource(name = "validator")
    private PushMessagePreValidator validator;

    @POST
    @Path("/register")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response registerDevice(PushWooshRegisterDeviceDto dto) {
        if (validator.validate(dto) == 200) {
            return invokePushMessage(dto, PushMessageType.REGISTER.getMsgType());
        } else {
            return buildFailResponse();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response ping(@PathParam("param") String param) {
        return Response.status(200).entity(param).build();
    }
```

GET method works as expected (basicly it works :) ), but POST method throws NullPointerException on line: if (validator.validate(dto) == 200).

I dont know why @Autowired annotation doesnt work here, ale i tried with @Resource - same effect.

Any tip may help.

Thanks in advance,
Marek.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Jersey with Spring, you need to utilize the Spring integration module - i.e. depend on jersey-spring and use SpringServlet instead of Jersey ServletContainer servlet class. See here for more info: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-spring/com/sun/jersey/spi/spring/container/servlet/package-summary.html

Comment: i hoped i can do it without jersey-spring, well ill add exludes on spring in this dependency and hopefully it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented the *org.springframework.validation.Validator* interface, you should see the the *validate* method expected two parameters, that is of type *Object* and of type *Errors*, so you need to add another class to your *validate* call

```
BeanPropertyBindingResult v = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(dto,"Errors");
validator.validate(dto, v);
```